# pstack equivalent in erlang

Tags: erlang, pstack

When a Erlang system hangs  I want to know what the system is doing during that time.  For a c/c++ program, I can easily run the pstack, but I didn't find out a handy tool for this purpose in Erlang.

1. What is the pstack equivalent in Erlang?
2. Actually I want to check the running stack trace of the following process.

   ```
   "/opt/couchbase/lib/erlang/erts-5.10.4.0.0.1/bin/beam.smp -P 327680 -K true -- -root /opt/couchbase/lib/erlang -progname erl --... "
   ```

   and I started a new Erlang shell and start the webtool and check the appmon  however I can't find the above application. What may cause this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Concerning `pstack` equivalent, have you read [Erlang Profiling](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/profiling.html) from official guide? It gives you lot of example on how to profile your application and find where your code stuck.

Another useful tools is [`observer`](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/observer/introduction_ug.html) it will show all working process, CPU usage, process stack and lot of more information.

If you don't see anything with these tools, you can try with [Erlang debugger](http://erlang.org/doc/man/dbg.html).

Now concerning couchbase, if your application is currently running, you can connect to it with [Erlang shell](http://erlang.org/doc/man/shell.html) and launch previous quoted commands and applications.

I don't know if you are using couchbase alone or with couchdb, but, if you want to use `observer` or other tools from command line, you can start [`couchdb`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/couchdb) with `-i` flag:

```sh
# -i use the interactive Erlang shell
couchdb -i
```

In case of your application run remotely without GUI, you can use [`etop`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/etop.html), its a CLI alternative to `observer`. You can also dump `etop` output to file if you don't want to run it directly from your Erlang shell. IHMO, if you want more information concerning I/O or debug, use `eprof`, `fprof` and other profiling tools with dump file (see also [`eep`](https://github.com/virtan/eep) profiling tool, easy to use).

Another alternative, if you are using SSH and want to see `observer` window, you can use [X11Forwarding](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/ssh.1#X11_FORWARDING) with ssh: `ssh -X $yourserver` or `ssh -Y $yourserver` and simply run `observer:start().` in your Erlang shell.

Comment: thanks you! but I still have some issue.  when I want to try observer, I found it is a gui program and I don't have GUI env for this purpose now.

Comment: thanks you!   But I still have some issue.  when I want to try observer, I found it is a gui program and I don't have GUI env for this purpose now.  when I want to use observerweb, I run to issue https://github.com/freecnpro/observerweb/issues/4.     about the -i flag,  per my understanding,  if there are some erlang process and no matter if it is couchdb or couchdb -i or not couchdb at all,  I think it should be able to verified with with the above tool.  I am probably wrong, I raise this just because I want to refresh my knowledge. Thanks!

Comment: ok, edited the answer with more information concerning profiling tool w/o GUI. Hope this will help! :)